# Why is carbonic acid a weaker acid than acetic acid?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base, resonance

Is it because the $\ce{OH}$ group next to $\ce{COOH}$ in carbonic acid donates electron density to the $\ce{COO-}$ by resonance, making it a stronger base, compared to a weaker electron donating inductive effect of $\ce{CH3}$ and thus its conjugate acid is weaker?

What does the resonance contribution look like in this case?

What makes resonance a stronger factor than induction?

Answer (score 13):

Before you ask "why", ask "if".

Carbonic acid is **not** weaker than acetic. In fact, it is stronger, just as one might expect by looking at that extra electron-withdrawing substituent. The trouble is, carbonic acid is also pretty unstable. At any given moment, most of it exists as $\ce{CO2}$. This leads to much lower *apparent* acidity.

Think of it this way: you add some acetic acid to a carbonate salt. An equilibrium sets in, much closer to the starting compounds than to the products. In other words, you'll have just a very tiny amount of $\ce{H2CO3}$. But as soon as you have it, it starts decomposing, thus shifting the equilibrium more and more to the right.

Look again at that [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbonic_acid), it says:

> 3.6 ($\rm pK_{a1}$ for $\ce{H2CO3}$ only), 6.3 ($\rm pK_{a1}$ including $\ce{CO2(aq)}$)...

Comment: This is something new! Thank you for this information. Although I'd like to ask, doesn't OH DONATE electron density by resonance, or is that not possible in this case?

Comment: Even if it does, that doesn't outweigh the electron-withdrawing effect.

Comment: @IvanNeretin but isn't inductive effect a weak effect and resonance a strong effect?

Comment: @Lalit No. Both can be either weak or strong. In this particular case, the inductive effect is relatively strong, and the resonance relatively weak.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Yeah, so it's an exception :-)

Answer (score 0):

The conjugate base of acetic acid is more stronger than carbonic acid because carbonate has $\ce{-OH}$ which shows +R effect but acetate has $\ce{-CH3}$ which shows +I effect.

Therefore, the electron density is little stronger in case of acetate.